# how to show active tab using url in mvc4

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

class

```
 public class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem(string area, string controller, string action,string name)
    {
        this.area = area;
        this.controller = controller;
        this.action = action;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public string area { get; set; }
    public string controller { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

~Layout.cshtml

```
 @Html.Action("_Menu", "User") //loading partial page
```

controller

```
  [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult _Menu()
    {

        List<MenuItem> obj = new List<MenuItem>();
        obj.Add(new MenuItem("Master", "User", "ViewProfile", "Profile"));
        obj.Add(new MenuItem("Master", "User", "StepI", "Upload Abstract"));
        obj.Add(new MenuItem("Master", "User", "ChangePass", "Change Password"));
        obj.Add(new MenuItem("", "home", "login", "Log Out"));           
        return PartialView(obj);
    }
```

_Menu.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Conference_Project.Areas.Master.Models.MenuItem>
@foreach (var item in Model)
 {
     <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
     <li role="presentation" class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString().ToLower() == item.action.ToLower() ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink(item.name, item.action, item.controller)</li>
   </ul>
 }
```

[image]

```
how to show active tab using url in mvc4
```

................................................. ...............................................................................

Comment: I assume you want the menu related to the current page to have the `class="active"`? What are the values of `item.action`, `item.controller` in each of those 2 menu items?

Comment: Are you just trying to move the active class from the `li` onto the `a`?

Comment: Pls check class and controller which i am passing data

Comment: If your wanting the menu for the current page to be 'active, then your code should be `class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == item.action ? "active" : "")"`. But if your navigating to `../Profile/ViewProfile`, then the code you have shown will add the `class="active"`. Have you checked the html your generating?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke what is wrong in my code  my url  is like  http://localhost:32912/Master/User/ViewProfile

Comment: Nothing if your navigating to `/User/ViewProfile`. You probably also want to ignore case (e.g. convert both values to lower case - e.g.`.ToString().ToLower() == item.action.ToLower()`

Comment: Also your code should be `<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">@foreach(...){ ... }</ul>` - you currently generating a `<ul>` for each menu item - it should only be one that contains a `<li>` for each item (not sure if that's the issue though)

Comment: @(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString().ToLower() == item.action.ToLower()  instead of this when I try like @("viewprofile" == item.action.ToLower() ? "active" : "") then work fine why this ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString().ToLower()  not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137533/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-pravin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calling a `ChildAction` to generate the partial (using `@Html.Action()`) so

```
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString()
```

returns `"_Menu"` (not the action name of the main view). Change your code to use

```
ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString()
```

so that you get the parent action.

As a side note, you should be generating one `<ul>` element, and I would recommend comparing the values ignoring case.

```
@model IEnumerable<Conference_Project.Areas.Master.Models.MenuItem>
@{
    string action = ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString().ToLower();
}
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li role="presentation" class="@(action == item.action.ToLower() ? "active" : "")">
            @Html.ActionLink(item.name, item.action, item.controller)
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```